# pipeline regressor ensemble with scikit-learn version 0.19.2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I'm using scikit-learn version 0.19.2 (for onnx conversion compatibility),
and I'm having problems implementing ensemble methods with `Pipeline`.

The code below is trying to implement linear regression from two independent regressors:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion  
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline  
from sklearn import linear_model  
import sklearn  

# data
X = [[1, 2, 2], [4, 5, 6]]
y = [1, 2]

# fitting models
forest_clf = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor()
forest_clf.fit(X, y)
logistic_clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
logistic_clf.fit(X,y)

# pipeline
estimators = [('random_forest',  forest_clf), ('logistic',  logistic_clf)]
model = Pipeline( steps=[ ('models', FeatureUnion(estimators) ), ('linear_regression', linear_model.base.LinearRegression() ) ] )

# fitting ensemble
model.fit(X,y)
```

resulting in error

```
TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform. 'RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse', max_depth=None,
           max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
           min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
           min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
           oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False)' (type ) doesn't
```

Can someone help me figuring what went wrong?

p.s I'm looking for some Pipeline technique to imitate the `sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor` from version 0.23.

Comment: Why are you using a `RandomForestRegressor` and `LogisticRegression` *classification* object?

Comment: @wundermahn I'm trying to make an ensemble of two regression objects, for example if `yF` is the output of the random forest and `yLR` is the output of the logistic regressor then I'm looking for the optimal output `y=a*yF+b*yLR+c`. Those two regressors are just an example.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) class:

> **Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’**, that is, they must implement fit and **transform methods**.

As the error message indicates, the `RandomForestRegressor` does not implement the transform function (neither does `LogisitcRegression`). Hence, they cannot be used directly as transformers in the pipeline.

If you want to use a pipeline, the only workaround I see is to wrap them in custom classes that implement the transform function as needed:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


class RFTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.rf = RandomForestRegressor()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.rf.fit(X, y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return self.rf.predict(X).reshape(-1, 1)


class LRTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.lr = LogisticRegression()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.lr.fit(X, y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return self.lr.predict(X).reshape(-1, 1)
```

These custom transformers will simply fit their respective models and the transform function will return their prediction (and if I understand correctly, this is what you want to concatenate and pass to the final estimator).

Now, you can use these transformers like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion


# Data
X = [[1, 2, 2], [4, 5, 6]]
y = [1, 2]

# Instantiate transformers
forest_clf = RFTransformer()
logistic_clf = LRTransformer()

# Pipeline
estimators = [('random_forest',  forest_clf), ('logistic',  logistic_clf)]
model = Pipeline(steps=[('models', FeatureUnion(estimators)), ('linear_regression', LinearRegression())])

# Fitting ensemble
model.fit(X, y)
```

Finally, just to confirm the desired output:

```
print(model.predict(X))

# Output
# [1. 2.]
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! I hope I'll be able to convert the pipeline to onnx later on. I've generalized the custom class for different models, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @afsharov answer, I've made a general class for custom transform:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn import linear_model 
import sklearn
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion

class customTransform(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, algo_type):
        # algo type
        if algo_type=='GradientBoosting':
            model = sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor()
        elif algo_type=='svm':
            model = linear_model.svm.SVR()
        elif algo_type=='LogisticRegression':
            model = linear_model.LogisticRegression(solver='newton-cg')
        elif algo_type=='sgd':
            model = linear_model.stochastic_gradient.SGDRegressor()
        elif algo_type=='LinearRegression':
            model = linear_model.base.LinearRegression()
        elif algo_type=='TheilSen':
            model = linear_model.theil_sen.TheilSenRegressor() 
        elif algo_type=='RandomForest':
            model = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mae') 

        # set the name and the model
        self.name = algo_type
        self.model = model
        setattr(self, algo_type, model)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # self.rf.fit(X,y)
        getattr(self, self.name).fit(X, y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        # self.rf.predict(X).reshape(-1, 1)
        return getattr(self, self.name).predict(X).reshape(-1,1) 

    def show(self):
        print( '{}: {}'.format( self.name, self.model ) )

# Data
X = [[1, 2, 2], [4, 5, 6]]
y = [1, 2]

# Instantiate transformers
boosting_clf = customTransform('GradientBoosting')
forest_clf = customTransform('RandomForest')
boosting_clf.show()

# Pipeline
estimators = [('random_forest',  forest_clf), ('gradient_boosting',  boosting_clf)]
model = Pipeline(steps=[ ('models', FeatureUnion(estimators)), ('linear_regression', linear_model.LinearRegression())] )

# Fitting ensemble
model.fit(X, y)

# predict
print(model.predict(X) )
```